# Why are my attempts to read content from txt file into dictionary failing?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

As the title suggests, I'm trying to read a file into a dictionary in Python. The error I'm getting is "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)". I've gone through different posts with the same error but the suggested solutions haven't been working for me.
My text file is formatted like:

```
яблоко:the round fruit of a tree of the rose family, which typically has thin red or green skin and crisp flesh. Many varieties have been developed as dessert or cooking fruit or for making cider
банан:a long curved fruit which grows in clusters and has soft pulpy flesh and yellow skin when ripe
вишня:a small, round stone fruit that is typically bright or dark red
```

So this (adapted from answers I found on other posts) should work:

```
myDict = {}
with open("fruits.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(":")
        myDict[key] = value
print(myDict)
```

But it's throwing the aformentioned error. Any ideas as to why?

Thank you very much for reading.

Comment: likely there's a line in your file that doesn't have a ":" in it to separate it. It could be a blank line.  You can use `try ... except ValueError` to allow you to skip bad lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting this in an answer as a follow up to my comment. Very likely you have lines in your file that don't have the separator. You can skip the bad lines like this

```
try:
    key, value = line.strip().split(":")
    myDict[key] = value
except ValueError:
    continue  # will just go to the next item in the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an `encoding` to open function. This code worked for me:

```
myDict = {}
with open("fruits.txt", encoding='utf8') as file:
    for line in file:
        key, value = line.strip().split(":")
        myDict[key] = value
print(myDict)
```

Comment: So I tried Cfreak's answer and it solved the problem I was asking about, but this solved the issue I discovered shortly after of getting the file content in Cyrillic to print to the console, so thank you too!